# How to limit number of result in pagination?

Tags: limit, cakephp-3.0

This is my action:

```
public function index()
    {
        $this->paginate = [
            'page' => 1,
            'limit' => 12,
            'maxLimit' => 12
        ];      
        $suppliers =$this->Suppliers->find('all')
            ->order(['Suppliers.description'=>'asc']);
        $suppliers = $this->paginate($suppliers);
        $this->set(compact('suppliers'));
        $this->set('_serialize', ['suppliers']);
    }
```

No matters value I put on limit, max limit.. he always give me all record from my database...

Comment: Can someone help me please??

Comment: Same code works as expected on my side. What version are you using? What DB engine are you using?